# With liferay how to give different permission to different users as their Roles?

Tags: liferay, portlet, liferay-6

With liferay how to give different permission to different users as their Roles?

I had just installed liferay Portal on my PC, what I want is to make one page and there are three users in that with different roles.  (e.g only view blog,  Only edit the blog entry,  view,  edit blog entry..etc..)

It was easy to create role and their permission, but some how I can't make it the way I wanted. I just want that same page can be accessed by users with different permission as their roles.

I had tried to Google for any tutorial for that kind of thing which can guide me but not found any good link, so is there any tutorial that can fulfill my requirement that how to give different permission on the same page. Can anyone provide me good reference link for tutorial of liferay permissions for user?

Answer (score 1):

I guess following link will do the job for you !

http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/8131940